# PowerShell: Using $env:userprofile in a desktop shortcut statically between users

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I have a PowerShell program that generates some number of new user accounts on the system. Within each user, I have a log folder that I create somewhere within the user account, and an associated desktop shortcut that links to that log folder. To do this, I set the shortcut's target path to something like `$env:userprofile + "\LogsFolder"`

The issue I'm running into is that, on the current account (the one that generates the new account and logs folders), the shortcut itself will retain the $env:userprofile variable. So when I navigate to `C:\Users\NewUser\shortcut`, I don't see the shortcut going to `C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder`, but instead it leads to `C:\Users\CurrentUser\LogsFolder`, which is entirely different.

If I log into NewUser, the shortcut will correctly navigate to `C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder`, but it leads to the wrong folder when I log back into CurrentUser. My question is, how can I store the $env:userprofile path statically when I generate these shortcuts, so that instead of `$env:userprofile\LogsFolder` I get `C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder`, and so the shortcut path remains static between different users?

Quick update for a better explanation: since administrator accounts can navigate to other user folders, I was hoping that an administrator account would be able to access the logs folder for each user individually, rather than having to log into the different users in order to grab their logs.

Update on the layout of the scripts: The administrator account runs the user generator script which creates the actual new user accounts, and it then has those user accounts run the shortcut/logging script that creates the new shortcuts on the desktop. I don't provide any usernames or parameters to the shortcut/logging script, and since it is run by the new user accounts, the $env:userprofile variable is used to tell the script where to put each shortcut. I wanted to avoid providing the username of each account to the script manually since it seemed like $env:userprofile would work fine, but since the shortcut itself changes between users, the solution that seems to make the most sense is to provide the account name directly to the shortcut/logging script so that it can generate the shortcuts statically. This requires modifying the overhaul structure of the shortcut/logging script however, which is the main issue and why I want the actual contents of $env:userprofile itself.

A sample of my code for reference:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject ("Wscript.shell")

# Correctly generates the shortcut on the new user/user who is running the script
$shortcut = $shell.createshortcut("$($env:USERPROFILE)\shortcut.lnk")

# Path changes depending on who is logged in
$shortcut.TargetPath = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\LogsFolder"

$shortcut.Save()
```

Desired behavior: $shortcut.TargetPath is statically set to "C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder"

Current behavior: $shortcut.TargetPath is either "C:\Users\CurrentUser\LogsFolder" or "C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder" depending on the current user.

Comment: Wait, you want a *static* path that does not change independently of who is logged in? That probably won't work as regular users don't have access to somebody else's profile, so pointing every user to `C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder` will result in access denied errors.

Comment: And if every user has their own shortcut and their own `LogsFolder` anyway, why would you expect anything *other* than every user using their own respective `LogsFolder`? I've read your question a couple of times now, but it doesn't add up.

Comment: I was hoping that the admin user account that generates the logs folder for all of the users would be able to navigate to each user's logs folder which would save me from having to log into each user account in order to grab the logs. Currently the dynamic setup works fine if I don't mind swapping user accounts, but I was hoping there would be a way for an admin account specifically to be able to navigate to each users' log folders. I'll update the question with this info though, thanks!

Comment: I guess I'm unclear what user account runs what part of the process. You seem to be setting up multiple profiles in a script that runs under an admin account. Why is that script not logging to a single place? Why are you switching accounts in the first place? When you want to use use static paths (i.e. paths without any environment variables) ... why aren't you? I'm still confused.

Comment: Updated the OP with a little bit more info on flow of the scripts and the reasoning behind it. Apologies if my question was unclear. It seems like the best solution is to use a static path as you and mklement0 have mentioned and so I'll take that approach instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), `"$($env:USERPROFILE)\..."` (which can be simplified to `"$env:USERPROFILE\..."`), *instantly* expands to the value of the `USERPROFILE` environment variable *as defined at that time*, and therefore uses the path for the account that *generates* the new user, not the one for the new user.

Therefore, you need the following:

```
# Create the shortcut file in the *new users*'s profile folder.
# This requires you to specify the path (ultimately) *literally, statically*.
# I'm assuming that the new user's username is stored in $newUser:
$newUserProfile = "C:\Users\$newUser"
$shell.createshortcut("$newUserProfile\shortcut.lnk")

# For a shortcut file created in a dir. specific to the new user,
# you *can* use an environment-variable reference as follows:
$shortcut.TargetPath = '%USERPROFILE%\LogsFolder'
# Alternatively, for a *static* value, use:
#  "$newUserProfile\LogsFolder"
```

Shortcut files (`.lnk`) support `cmd.exe`-style, *unexpanded* environment-variable references, which are expanded *at the time the shortcut is opened*, which, when logged in as the new user, will then expand to *their* profile dir.

Comment: But that contradicts *"Desired behavior: $shortcut.TargetPath is statically set to "C:\Users\NewUser\LogsFolder""*. Either I'm crazy, or the OP's concept of static and dynamic paths is heavily warped.

Comment: Good point, @Tomalak - I hadn't considered all angles; please see my update.

Comment: Yeah that's the point that I deleted my answer because I was confused, but it probably is what the OP is trying to do.